# Sychronous animations in knockout binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-animate

I want to apply animations when certain properties change with my knockout models (specifically a movement). I need these animations to be synchronous, if there is more than one going on things will get very confusing for the user.

I would like to use a knockout custom binding to do this, as it should make my code easier to understand, but if I do that I can't provide a callback function to the jquery animation. I know that I can't have true synchronous behavior due to javascript limitations, but I can't figure out how to fake it.

The behavior I want:
http://jsfiddle.net/3fLvpxLc/2/

```
$("#e1").animate({left: 50}, "slow", function() {
    // more animations
}
```

The version with synchronization problems:
http://jsfiddle.net/hrwsd1z3/1/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.position = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
        $(element).animate({left: valueUnwrapped}, "slow");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a rather vague description - can you provide something more tangible like jsfiddle or at least a concept of code with the problem?

Comment: I added jsfiddles. Does that help you understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery queues](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) are your friend. With them you can serialize asynchronous animations.

Usually they are used implicitly for all animation effects you do on one element, i.e. tied to the animated element *itself*:

```
$("element").show("slow").animate({left: 25});
```

But you can use them explicitly, too. `queue` adds an animation to the queue, the `next` callback dequeues the next animation (you can conveniently pass it as the `complete` handler). That way you can tie the animations to a *different* element than the animated one:

```
$("#container").queue(function (next) {
    $("element").show("slow", next);
}
$("#container").queue(function (next) {
    $("element").animate({left: 25}, next);
}
```

With that knowledge the task becomes simple:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.syncPosition = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var newPosition = ko.toJS(valueAccessor());

        // set element to its initial position
        $(element).css(newPosition);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var newPosition = ko.toJS(valueAccessor());

        // queue position update as animation to a common element, e.g. the body
        $(document.body).queue(function( next ) {
            $(element).animate(newPosition, "slow", next);
        });
    }
};

function Item(id, top, left) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.position = {
         top: ko.observable(top),
         left: ko.observable(left)
    };
}
function VM(params) {
    var self = this;
    
    self.elements = ko.observableArray([
        new Item("e1"),
        new Item("e2"),
        new Item("e3")
    ]);
}

var vm = new VM();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.elements()[0].position.left(50);
vm.elements()[1].position.left(75);
vm.elements()[2].position.left(25);
vm.elements()[1].position.left(125);
vm.elements()[2].position.top(10);
vm.elements()[1].position.top(20);
vm.elements()[0].position.top(30);
vm.elements()[0].position.left(0);
vm.elements()[1].position.left(0);
vm.elements()[2].position.left(0);
```

```css
div.container {
    position: relative;
}
div.container > div {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
#e1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
#e2 {
    background-color: red;
}
#e3 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="container" data-bind="foreach: elements">
    <div data-bind="syncPosition: position, attr: {id: id}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is clear that this is the solution, but I am having some trouble understanding why. I have seen other people recommending queues, but I haven't seen a complete explanation of how precisely they work. From what I understand, all the of the jquery animations are put on the "fx" queue of the element that is being animated. In your second example `$("#container").queue(...);`, it seems like the items would be dequeued from the body's queue, then added to "element"s fx queue, thus still resulting in simultaneous animations. With your jsfiddle, this isn't the case. Why not?

Comment: Queues are the backbone of every animation in jQuery, since *all* animations are asynchronous. You can do `$(".foo").show("slow").hide("slow")` and that call returns *immediately*, yet the element itself shows slowly and *after that* hides slowly. What really happens is that `show()` internally calls `queue()` on that element, and immediately after that `hide()` calls `queue()` on that element, and then there are two animations on the stack that pop off and play out one after another - it's just that the jQuery API hides that from you.

Comment: To answer your question - yes, I push the animation on the element's own `fx` queue. But I use the `next()` callback of the *container's* queue. The container effectively does nothing. I just halt its queue until I choose to call `next()` - which, by accident, if you will, is precisely when `element` has finished animating.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Oh, I see what I missed. I missed that the functions you were manually pushing onto the queue received a callback argument which they passed to the animation. Now everything makes sense.